# Task hook seems to not be JSON-serializable

Tags: java, apache-storm

I had a working Storm topology that I tweaked by adding a task hook and now I'm getting an error saying my config is not json-serializable.  The error occurs when the topology is submitted to the LocalCluster.

I suspect my problem is that I'm not configuring the task hook properly.  In my topology driver class, just before I submit the topology I do this:

```
config.put(config.TOPOLOGY_AUTO_TASK_HOOKS, new RubeGoldbergTaskHook());
```

Where config is of type backtype.storm.Config,
and RubeGoldbergTaskHook extends BaseTaskHook

Am I not setting the config.TOPOLOGY_AUTO_TASK_HOOKS property correctly or do I need to modify my RubeGoldbergTaskHook class to be JSON-serializable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use in this way.
It will work...

```
List<String> hooksList= new ArrayList<String>();
hooksList.add(RubeGoldbergTaskHook.class.getName());
conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_AUTO_TASK_HOOKS, hooksList);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you do want to use a java instance in the configuration map, there is an alternative: you can serialize in kryo (as it is provided with Storm) to a byte array and then converting it to a base 64 string. That way, you will be able to deserialize any java instance from storm configuration in any bolt. Hope that it is useful.